# Request analytics page for azure api management using azure sdk

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-sdk-.net

I want to request the analytics page from azure portal of an azure api management.

[image]

I searched in the package azure.resourcemanager.apimanagament but i didn't find anything.

If you know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

*By looking at your API management instance, it seems like its in provisioning state.*

When you will create your APIM instance, you will see below, which means its still in provisioning state.

[image]

[image]

Once the instance is successfully created, you will no longer see **Service is being activated** notification and you will see below

[image]

Then all the APIs and the list of operations in it, will automatically reflect in **Analytics**.

[image]

[image]